# PowerShell create WMI Class

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm trying to create a WMI class and populate it

I can't quite get my head around "Enumeration Available"

I know how to make `InvalidExtensions` enumerable but I don't understand how to populate this field when creating a WMI instance

I also don't understand how to prefill `Possible Enumeration Values`

My code so far

```
$newClass = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass("root\cimv2", [String]::Empty, $null); 
$newClass["__CLASS"] = "Test"; 
$newClass.Qualifiers.Add("Static", $true)

$newClass.Properties.Add("Username",[System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
$newClass.Properties["Username"].Qualifiers.Add("Key", $true)

$newClass.Properties.Add("TotalFileCount",[System.Management.CimType]::UInt16, $false)

$newClass.Properties.Add("TotalFolderCount",[System.Management.CimType]::UInt16, $false)

$newClass.Properties.Add("TotalSizeMB",[System.Management.CimType]::UInt16, $false)

$newClass.Properties.Add("InvalidFileNameCount",[System.Management.CimType]::UInt16, $false)

$newClass.Properties.Add("InvalidExtensionCount",[System.Management.CimType]::UInt16, $false)

$newClass.Properties.Add("InvalidExtensions",[System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
$newClass.Properties["InvalidExtensions"].Qualifiers.Add("Values",$true)

$newClass.Put()

Set-WmiInstance -Class Test -Argument @{Username="testaccount";TotalFileCount="5191";TotalFolderCount="355";TotalSizeMB="3660";InvalidFileNameCount="10";InvalidExtensionCount="2";InvalidExtensions=".appx",".ost"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out how to add the values

Changed

`$newClass.Properties.Add("InvalidExtensions",[System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)`

to

`$newClass.Properties.Add("InvalidExtensions",[System.Management.CimType]::String,"StringArray")`

Then a standard array can be used when adding values

I still don't know how to set possible values in the class properties

Comment: Just curious.   But why do this in PowerShell?   vs just using Visual Studio and the languages there and the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/creating-a-class#:~:text=Creating%20a%20WMI%20Class%201%20Base%20Class.%20A,that%20describe%20that%20class.%20...%203%20Related%20topics).   What is your use case?

Comment: Have an existing PowerShell script that does auditing, don't want to reinvent the wheel but need to make a new WMI class to store data to be collected by SCCM
Long way of doing things I know

Comment: Hummm...  yeppers, sure is a long way around the cart...  not something I'd ever considered or tried.